# Log website performance client side

Tags: networking

I have a client that is have an issue (it's slow) with a website on one of my servers. The server is a windows 2003 box running WebSphere 6.1.

I can't find anything in the logs that would indicates an issue.

Is there some free software out there that can help me figure out why the site is slow on the client's end?

The client has an IT department, but I need to be sure it's not my side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Networking issues, **Tracert** is your best friend. It'll give you an idea of any problems between the client and you.

Otherwise its a website issue, which I'd use **Firefox + Firebug** for diagnosing any loading / java script issues with the website.

Comment: You mean Tracer T right!? ;) http://nextgenhacker101.com/